# How to use Opensea.io in my local web server (localhost 8000)

Tags: python, java, html, opensea

How can i use Opensea.io SDK in my localhost.. i am trying to check for vulnerabilities in the code and want to see it from my local web server. so basically after cloning the github or downloading the zip from the project opensea github ( https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js ) how do i get it to show on my local host.. also can you try it and give me steps to reproduce.. I know at first i do npm i to install all dependencies then it shows some dependencies are out of date so i npx npm-check-updates -u then i do npm update but thats all i know what next should i do to make it show on my local server. also what cd should i use is it cd opensea-js. I tried npm start but it gave me error codes

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The main question is how do i get it to show up on a local server